# How to change the color of jQuery Mobile Listview

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, themeroller

I want to change the color of one of the `<li>` record to say "Red". Please suggest how can I do the same.

Comment: which one ? the selected one ? a random one ?

Comment: I just want to add a class. Just a random one keeping the gradient constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery Mobile ThemeRoller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/) to customize swatches to any colors you would like. You can have multiple swatches (from A-Z) and utilize them on an element-level with `data-theme="a"` (insert letter of swatch).

Here's a theme I made for you that is ALL red. http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/?ver=1.1.1&style_id=20120725-62

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know you have chosen an answer already, but modifying the listview's anchor tag should do the trick. I had this (where #storeList is the name of my unordered list):

```
#storeList a {
    background-color:red;
}
```